# Reordering multiple siblings based on a property

Tags: xslt

I want to produce an HTML file like this example:

> ## English
>
> [image: Alt]
>
> En Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.
>
> ## Français
>
> Fr Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.

From the following example XML source, on which I have no control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<content id="">
    <header language="en">
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCNw.gif" />
        <!-- more header-related elements -->
    </header>
    <header language="fr">
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <img src="" />
        <!-- more header-related elements -->
    </header>
    <html language="en" type="source">
    <![CDATA[
        <p>En Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
        ]]>
    </html>
    <html language="fr" type="source">
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Fr Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
        ]]>
    </html>
</content>
```

So I wrote this XSLT to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h1>English</h1>
        <hr/>
        <xsl:for-each select="content/header">
            <xsl:call-template name="header">
                <xsl:with-param name="lang">en</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="content/html">
            <xsl:call-template name="html">
                <xsl:with-param name="lang">en</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <hr/>
        <h1>Français</h1>
        <hr/>
        <xsl:for-each select="content/header">
            <xsl:call-template name="header">
                <xsl:with-param name="lang">fr</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="content/html">
            <xsl:call-template name="html">
                <xsl:with-param name="lang">fr</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="header" match="*">
        <xsl:param name='lang'/>
        <xsl:if test="current()[@language=$lang]">
            <xsl:if test="enabled[normalize-space(text())='true']">
                <xsl:call-template name="image"/>
                <!-- more header-related elements -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="image" match="*">
        <xsl:if test="img[not(normalize-space(@src)='')]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="img"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="html" match="*">
        <xsl:param name='lang'/>
        <xsl:if test="current()[@language=$lang]">
            <xsl:value-of select="node()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That said, my solution feels very verbose, but seems to enable useful composition and reutilization properties, which are two things very important to me, since I will need to transform lots of XML documents whose structure is similar to this example; and thus, if most of my XSLTs can reuse parts of other XSLTs, this will be very useful.

A few notes of interest:

- Transformation *speed* is of no importance, although it might be interesting to learn more on this aspect.
- The transformations will **never** need to handle XML documents which encode more than the 2 example languages (*en* and *fr*).

So I would like to learn if my solution looks either anti-idiomatic-or even plain wrong-to you, XSLT wranglers.

Comment: You wrote [it] *seems to enable useful composition and reutilization properties*. I don't think so with those CDATA sections...

Comment: Yes, but I have no control on the XML source. :\

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that doesn't use any xslt conditional directives and any named templates.

Comment: See if this helps you [xslt-how-to-reordering-and-alternate-styling-based-on-position](http://www.inspiredbytechnology.com/index.php/2011/08/08/xslt-how-to-reordering-and-alternate-styling-based-on-position/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation doesn't contain any conditional XSLT instructions or any named templates**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <my:langs>
  <lang short="en">English</lang>
  <lang short="fr">Français</lang>
 </my:langs>

 <xsl:variable name="vLangs" select="document('')/*/my:langs/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="header">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  <hr/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "../html[@language=current()/@language]/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header/@language">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="$vLangs[@short=current()]"/></h1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header[enabled='true']/img[@src and not(@src='')]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="html/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="html|text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<content id="">
    <header language="en">
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCNw.gif" />
        <!-- more header-related elements -->
    </header>
    <header language="fr">
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <img src="" />
        <!-- more header-related elements -->
    </header>
    <html language="en" type="source">
    <![CDATA[
             <p>En Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
             <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
             ]]>
   </html>
    <html language="fr" type="source">
    <![CDATA[
            <p>Fr Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
            ]]>
 </html>
</content>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<h1>English</h1>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCNw.gif" />
<hr />

             <p>En Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
             <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>

   <h1>Français</h1>
<hr />

            <p>Fr Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The use of templates and pattern matching**.
2. **The use of** `<xsl:apply-templates>`
3. **The use of predicates** both in the match pattern of the templates and for selecting the necessary node-list in `<xsl:apply-templates>`

Comment: I like a lot the pattern matching you put in place. This makes for very modular templates. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Weirdly, this code `<xsl:value-of select="$vLangs[@short=current()]"/>` made my oldish xalan-based implementation fail with a `NullPointerException`. (And @Flack's equivalent code, too.) So until I can have the XSLT processor upgraded, I skip the sweet variable usage and simply output the language's short name.

Comment: @Daniel-Jomphe: An attempt for a workaround would be: `<xsl:variable name="vCur" select="string(.)"/> <xsl:value-of select="$vLangs[@short=$vCur]"/>`

Comment: @Dimitre-Novatchev: I tried it with no success. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would've wrote it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="my:my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<my:language-labels>
    <lang code="en" label="English"/>
    <lang code="fr" label="Francais"/>
</my:language-labels>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="header"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:variable name="curLang" select="@language"/>
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/my:language-labels/lang[@code = $curLang]/@label"/>
    </h1>
    <hr/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="img[not(normalize-space(@src) = '')][../enabled[normalize-space() = 'true']]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="../html[@language = $curLang]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your HTML sample looks broken, so I may be a little wrong. My result is:

```
<h1>English</h1>
<hr>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCNw.gif"> 
<p>En Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
<h1>Francais</h1> 
<hr>
<p>Fr Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Nunc rutrum, eros sit amet ornare faucibus.</p>
```

**Notes:**

1. Use predicates. It is a very powerful instrument.
2. Keep hardcoded data in one place if possible.
3. apply-templates it's not a mysterious tool but a very essential XSLT mechanism.
4. You can call normalize-space and other functions without actually passing an argument, if the argument you need is the context element.

Comment: Very concise!!! Thank you very much for the answer and the notes. Although I accepted @Dimitre Novatchev's answer, I still used some of your insight and tips.